# Difficulties with Xdebug and PhpStorm. Script trace is not written to one file. PhpStorm does not display all script trace

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, backtrace

There are two unclear points.

1. When you enable script tracing, not one file with the trace log is created, but several. For example trace3125.xt, trace3125.062513.xt, trace3125.018082.xt, etc. In the configuration, I indicated that the name of the trace file is formed as 
   `xdebug.trace_output_name = trace%p`. 
   Accordingly, the main log is in this trace3125.xt file, and in the remaining files the pieces of this log are from different time ranges. Why is the log not written to a single file? How can this be corrected?
2. When I insert the trace log into the window of the PhpStorm "Analyze Stack Trace" tool, it is inserted completely, and after processing by the application, part of it disappears. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Xdebug creates more than one trace file if it detects that there is more than one request at the same time.

   If Xdebug is instructed to create a new trace file, it checks whether one with the `trace%p` format already exists. If it is, and **is currently being written too**, Xdebug will add a random number to the file name, such as the `.018082` in one of your examples. It does that so that it doesn't write traces for two requests at the same time, as that could cause a race condition.
2. Perhaps there is either something in the trace file that PhpStorm does not like. I would suggest you file a bug report for that at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues where you should then also upload your trace file so that they can check it.